Can I sink the 5V+ pin into a GPIO in open drain mode?

I just discovered 'open drain' mode in the libgpiod documentation and was wondering if a raspberry pi open drain pin can sink the current / handle the voltage from its own 5V pin via a pullup resistor, allowing me two switch with 5V (example above).
If a high enough resistor value is chosen, could it do this? How about 5V from a different supply, or even 12V?

what is your understanding of what open drain means?

That the pin is disconnected when inactive, and pulled to ground when active, a mode enabled by calling an OPEN_DRAIN mode set with libgpiod.

Given the overall state of libgpiod, I'm not surprised they would screw up the definition of open drain also. Why would you take someone's word on hardware when they cannot even write a decent piece of software? You should do some reading and research first - learn for yourself what "open drain" means...  then you can kick yourself in the pants for taking someone else's word for it.

@seamus it wasn't libgpiod's fault. What don't you like about libgpiod and what would yiu usw instead?

@cmc: I don't know how you figure it "wasn't libgpiod's fault", but I'll gladly leave that to you to ponder. And rather than hearing what I don't like about libgpiod, I'd encourage you to evaluate it for yourself... form your own opinion. What I use instead is pinctrl; or perhaps wiringPi for anything except a Pi5.

@Seamus Interesting, thanks.
libgpiod docs did not give me incorrect information on what an open drain is, only that one can be enabled.
libgpiod 2.1 works fine for me. The C API is comprehensive but the API seems needlessly complex in some ways. But since working around that only takes a bit of boilerplate, the benefit of having a single tool for all pi versions outweights that drawback.

libgpiod is a hardware independent interface to the GPIO driver. AFAIK the Pi SoC do not support open drain the pin is either INPUT or OUTPUT.
The Pi is a 3.3V device so connecting a pin to 5V risks damaging the device or putting the chip in a lockup state (this turns the connection into a 4 layer device i.e. a SCR) if the current is limited.
It is unclear what you plan to do or WHY you would want to drive a P channel MOSFET. Your circuit will switch the Vgs between 1.7v  & 5V - it is unclear what the MOSFET will do.
NOTE you do not need a resistor. Conventionally MOSFET circuits include a high value resistor between gate and source to drain the gate capacitance but if driven by an active source this is unnecessary.

Thanks! The resistor was a symbolic load, it's a 3A motor but I just wanted to focus on the pin driving.

You would need a resistor from the open drain pin down to ground in order that the voltage on the open drain pin could never exceed 3.3 volts. So anything less than 20k (given the 10k you have to the 5v supply) would do this.
